# Missing regions for BI Engine in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-bi-engine

The docs for BI Engine say that *"BI Engine supports the same regions as BigQuery"*, yet many BigQuery regions seem to be missing when I go to use it:

[image]

https://cloud.google.com/bi-engine/docs/overview#supported_regions

Why aren't all the BigQuery regions listed? I need to be able to test it in Sydney.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the beta, the BI Engine team hasn't yet enabled the service in Sydney or some of the other regions where BigQuery is available. [The documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bi-engine/docs/overview#supported_regions) has been updated now to reflect the actual regions where you can use BI Engine.

Comment: Thanks Elliott. Obviously disappointed it's not available in Sydney, but at least it's clear now why :)

Comment: Yeah, hopefully it'll be available in Sydney soon!